# Clojure merge record type

Tags: clojure

It seems passing a record as the first argument to `merge` always returns a
record of the same type:

```
(defrecord X [a b c])
(merge (X. 1 2 3) {:d 4 :e 5})        ;; #my_ns.X{:a 1, :b 2, :c 3, :d 4, :e 5}
(merge {:z 0} (X. 1 2 3) {:d 4 :e 5}) ;; {:z 0, :a 1, :b 2, :c 3, :d 4, :e 5}
```

Looking at the `merge` implementation, it seems to rely on `conj`:

```
(conj (X. 1 2 3) [:z 0]) ;; #my_ns.X{:a 1, :b 2, :c 3, :z 0}
```

`assoc` works as well:

```
(assoc (X. 1 2 3) :z 0) ;; #my_ns.X{:a 1, :b 2, :c 3, :z 0}
```

It it behaviour I can rely on:

- in the case of `conj`?
- in the case of `merge`?
- in the case of `assoc`? (I assume that yes, since this seems used in
  StuartSierra/component quite heavily)

Comment: You may be able to get a more authoritative answer posting this question on the Clojure mailing list:  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/clojure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For conj and assoc, I would say definitely yes, you can rely on this, as those functions exist primarily to call through to your collection's polymorphic `IPersistentCollection/cons` and `Associative/assoc` methods. I would be less certain about relying on that for merge, as it is not "primarily" about polymorphic dispatch.

But in general Clojure doesn't really have "language lawyers", because there is no spec aside from "what does the canonical Clojure implementation do?" So while it's great to try to avoid relying on implementation details, it's not always clear what is an implementation detail and what is a "contract". I would say that pragmatically, merge is unlikely to change implementation anytime soon, and you will probably do yourself little harm by relying on it to use the polymorphic functions of its first argument.